# Array of pointers to linked list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I need to know if i want to make an array that every element of the array is a pointer to a linked list and pass the array to a function, the function is `void` because I need to change the array

```
typedef struct n{
  char *S;
  int num;
}list;

int (main){
list *Array[50];
return 0;
}
```

should the function be `void changeArray(list A[]);` or `void changeArray(list *A[]);` or `void changeArray(list **A[]);`

Comment: `void changeArray(list *A[]);`

Comment: why ?
the Array when i pass it to the function take the pointer with it ..
the element of the array is an address to an linked list .. if change the element of the array (address ) the element changes not the copy

Comment: you can write test code.

Comment: it works but i need a answer O.o

Comment: Other's does not fit the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function could be either `void changeArray(list *A[])` or `void changeArray(list **A)`. Both signatures would accept an array of pointers, and let you change elements of that array:

```
void changeArray(list *A[]) {
    ...
    A[0] = malloc(list);
}
```

Comment: why ? the Array when i pass it to the function take the pointer with it .. the element of the array is an address to an linked list .. if change the element of the array (address ) the element changes not the copy

Comment: @cip Arrays passed to functions are not copied. Instead, they "decay" to pointers. When you modify `A` inside your function, the array that you pass will be modified. If you would like to pass a copy of the array, either wrap it in a `struct`, or make a copy explicitly with `memcpy`.

Comment: that the point ! the element of the array is an address if i change it in the function it changes in real why i need a pointer then?
why the function will not be just `void change(list A[]); `

Comment: @cip Because your `Array` is an array of pointers. Each element of the array is a pointer to list, but the array itself becomes a two-star-pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer. Had `Array` been declared as `list Array[50]`, then `void change(list A[]);` would be the right signature. However, since you declared it with an asterisk, i.e. `list *Array[50]`, you need a second asterisk in the signature of the function that receives your array.

Answer (score 1):

The array is defined like

```
list *Array[50];
```

So if you want to pass this array to a function then it should be declared like

```
void changeArray( list *Array[50], size_t n );
```

or

```
void changeArray( list *Array[], size_t n );
```

or

```
void changeArray( list **Array, size_t n );
```

and called like

```
changeArray( Array, 50 );
```

In any case a declaration of an array as a function parameter is adjusted to a pointer to object of the type of elements of the array.

Comment: why ? the Array when i pass it to the function take the pointer with it .. the element of the array is an address to an linked list .. if change the element of the array (address ) the element changes not the copy

Comment: @cip The array is converted to a pointer to its first element that is the parameter will have actual type list **.The whole array is not copied into the function.

Comment: @cip So if you will change elements pointed to by the pointer you will change the original array not its copy.